# Подключаю OpenCV в QtCreator

Tags: qt, opencv, qtcreator

Пытаюсь подключить `OpenCV` в `QtCreator`.

Следую  [этой](http://hryu.livejournal.com/151430.html) инструкции

**В pro файле пишу**:

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui

TARGET = cvHello
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app
INCLUDEPATH += C:/qtOpenCV/opencv/build/include
LIBS += "C:/qtOpenCV/opencv/build/bin/*.dll"

SOURCES += main.cpp
OTHER_FILES += \
    img.JPG
```

`QtCreator` не видит подключаемых библиотек, подскажите почему.